# Serial.println printing whole alphabet when it should only one character

Tags: arrays, pointers, printing, arduino, arduino-c++

I am working on an Arduino powered device. It should display on a tripple seven segment display (using multiplexing) a number from capacitor charge.

I can read the charge, map it to numbers 0-100 (for percent). But when I want it to show on display, it does so only for a few seconds and then hangs on the last digit.

I tried to debug it with Serial.println outputs.
A few seconds it works ok and shows the right numbers. Then it starts showing numbers intertwened with free lines and something like this character ؟.
When I try to print out characters it works for a few second and then it prints out the whole alphabet like this !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?.

In the code I am transforming a number in the interval 0 - 100 to a binary representation for seven segment display.
I do it through a pointer array.
The pointer array is defined in a header file in a class as const.
Could the pointers be a problem?

This is the class with the pointer array codes:

```
class Display {
public:
    Display(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
    Display();
    void Show(uint8_t values[]);
    void Show(uint8_t);
    uint8_t* Decode(uint8_t);

private:
    uint8_t* an;
    uint8_t* ca;
  //                                        252           96        218         242         102         182         190         224         254         246           0
    const uint8_t* codes = new uint8_t[11]{0b11111100, 0b01100000, 0b11011010, 0b11110010, 0b01100110, 0b10110110, 0b10111110, 0b11100000, 0b11111110, 0b11110110, 0b00000000};
};
```

This is the code I use.

```
uint8_t* Display::Decode(uint8_t number) {
    uint8_t* digits = new uint8_t[3]{codes[10], codes[10], codes[10]};
    uint8_t offset = 2;
    if (number == 0) {
        digits[2] = codes[0];
    }
    else
      while (number > 0) {
          Serial.println("a"); //<<<--- this is the only println in the whole program
          digits[offset] = codes[number % 10];
          number /= 10;
          offset--;
      }
    return digits;
}

void Display::Show(uint8_t values[]) {
    for (uint8_t t = 0; t < 10; t++)
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //kolka cast sedemsegmentovky
            for (uint8_t o = 0; o < 3; o++) //kolka anoda na sedemsegmentovke
                digitalWrite(ca[o], LOW);
            for (uint8_t o = 0; o < 8; o++) //rozsvieti jednotlive segmenty
                //digitalWrite(an[o], bitRead(values[i], 7-o));
                digitalWrite(an[o], ((values[i] >> (7-o)) & 0b00000001));
            digitalWrite(ca[i], HIGH);
            delayMicroseconds(1);
        }
}

void Display::Show(uint8_t number) {
    Show(Decode(number));
}
```

I use it like this

```
chargeDisplay.Show(chargePercentage);
```

This is the output. The last line repeats indefinitly. There should be only "a" characters.

a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?

Comment: In your `uint8_t* Display::Decode(uint8_t number)` function, you're allocating memory every time you call the function (`new uint8_t`), but you never release it (i.e. no `delete` operation). I haven't tested the code, but that might be the issue, using up all the available memory.

Comment: yes, you are right, i added delete[] values; in the end of the Show and it works fine.